# How to compile a library for a fixed address in microblaze

Tags: c, gcc, microblaze

I want to build a library which is relocatable (ie. nothing other than local variables.  I also want to force the location of the library to be at a fixed location in memory.  I think this has to be done in the makefile, but I am confused as to what I have to do to force the library to be loaded at a fixed location.  This is using mb-gcc.

The reason I need this is I want to write a loader where I dont want to clobber over the code that is actually doing the copy of the other program.  So I want the program that is doing the copying to be located somewhere else at a location that is not being used (ie. ddr).

If I have all the functions that do the compiled into a library, what special makefile arguments do I need to force this to be loaded at location 0x80000000 for example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You write a [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.21/ld/Scripts.html#Scripts), and tell the compiler/linker to use it by using the `-T script.ld` option (to `gcc` and/or `ld`, depending on how you build your firmware files).

In your library C source files, you can use the `__attribute__((section ("name")))` syntax to put your [functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) and [variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes) into a specific *section*. The linker script can then decide where to put each section -- often at a fixed address for these kinds of devices. (You'll often see macro declarations like `#define FIRMWARE __attribute__((section(".text.firmware")))` or similar, to make the code easier to read and understand.)

If you create a separate firmware file just for your library, then you don't need to add the attributes to your code, just write the linker script to put the `.text` (executable code), `.rodata` (read-only constants), and `.bss` (uninitialized variables) sections at suitable addresses.

A web search for `microblaze "linker script"` finds some useful examples, and even more guides. Some of them must be suitable for your tools.